# ReportSize in Excel not the same as in PDF

Tags: ssrs-2008, reportviewer, rdlc, report-viewer2010

I have done already a lot of small (and also bigger reports) with report viewer 2010. In most cases I give the user the possibility to select the destination-format (PDF, Excel and sometimes also word).
However I always encouter the problem that the page format settings are applied different in the different output formats: If I create a report and optimize it to PDF, set the page size and the borders, then design the report, the report looks good (Measures are correct, borders are correct). However if I export it to Excel, it always is to big. What in PDF gives me one page, is in excel on two pages (horizontally).

- I checked the page borders in excel because I have read that there was a bug in an ancient report viewer with this, but they are exactly as specified in the reports properties. The paper size is also correct.
- I also have set the report width over the properties grid (via F4) to PageWidth-LeftBorder-RightBorder, but this is the same.
- I have also played around with the InteractiveSize, but this seems not to have an influence.

Is there something special to know about Excel-Exports from report viewer or is there a known bug? Has someone a solution for this behaviour?
It seems to me that in excel the same page format has half an inch less size than in pdf. Up to now I was never be able to create an exact copy of some paper report template. In the end, it was always something like making handicraft work, but I don't like that. I would like to understand whats going on.

As an additional information, I specify all metrics in centimeter, may be there is a problem with that? And the office is office 2010.

Comment: Were you ever able to find a reason for why this was happening?  I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: @Ryan: No, I have capitulated. The excel-export is in many things not very accurate. Worst of all are page footers. And the deviation varies also with the applied service-packs of report viewer. The user has to make the decision if he wants a nice view (pdf or word) or a practical format (excel). Both toghether seems not to exist.

Comment: @Ryan: I have added an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A real solution to this problem I have not found. Maybe this connect entry promises somethin for the future:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/636407/rdlc-excel-export-margin-problem#